# Ninject Dependency Injection - Two Concrete classes

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, ninject

I am learning Ninject for dependency injection and have a use case where two classes implement the same interface in a WPF MVVM applicaiton. In my research the dependencies can be bound using contextual bindings, however I am unsure of how that would work in this scenario.

For example:

```
public interface IModifyContent {
    string ModifyOperation();
}

public class UpdateContent : IModifyContent {
    public string ModifyOperation() {
        return "This is the update operation";
    }
}

public class DeleteContent : IModifyContent {
    public string ModifyOperation() {
        return "This is the delete operation";
    }
}

public class ModifyFile {
    private IFileManager _fileManager;
    private IModifyContent _modifyContent;
    
    public ModifyFile(IFileManager fileManager, IModifyContent modifyContent) 
    {
        _fileManager = _fileManager;
        _modifyContent = modifyContent;
    }
    
    public void Modify() 
    {
        var fileContent = _fileManager.ReadFileContents(); // Returns file content
        
        var result = _modifyContent.ModifyOperation(); // ModifyOperation would actually modify content in some way...
        
        // Do stuff with result
    }
}
```

Then the binding would look something like this:

```
Bind<IModifyContent>().To<UpdateContent>();
Bind<IModifyContent>().To<DeleteContent>();
// Other bindings
```

In this my thinking is as follows:

- ModifyFile class is used for common funcitonaility when modifying a file, whereas the two concrete implementations of IModifyContent define the unique behaviour that can occur for the different operations.
- Depending on what calls/ invokes ModifyFile I want to pass in a different concrete implementation of IModifyContent. I.e When calling from update business logic or view model, then the concrete UpdateContent should be passed as the dependency to ModifyFile.

Firstly is this a good design approach to avoid repeating common logic and secondly how can I inject the correct concrete implementation depending on what class/ invokes ModifyFile?

Comment: You might want to check whether those two classes should implement the same interface. You might be violating the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way through which you can achieve this !!!

You can register dependencies with specific name.

```
IKernel ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();

// Defining Bindings with specific names
ninjectKernel.Bind<IModifyContent>().To<UpdateContent>().Named("Update");
ninjectKernel.Bind<IModifyContent>().To<DeleteContent>().Named("Delete");
```

You can resolved these dependencies at compile time as shown below:

```
// Resolving dependencies using binding name
IModifyContent updateContent = ninjectKernel.Get<IModifyContent>("Update");
IModifyContent deleteContent = ninjectKernel.Get<IModifyContent>("Delete");
```

Once resolve they can be use to execute their codes. Below is the sample code which refers to the implementation that you have provided.

```
Console.WriteLine(updateContent.ModifyOperation());
Console.WriteLine(deleteContent.ModifyOperation());

// Output
// This is the update operation
// This is the delete operation
```

You can resolve such dependencies at run time as well.
For more information refer to the following link:

https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding

Answer (score 0):

I think that if your two concrete classes are from different business flows,
you can register them as concrete classes and not by abstraction.

I mean you can register

```
Bind<UpdateContent>().To<UpdateContent>();
Bind<DeleteContent>().To<DeleteContent>();
```

And In your BusinessLogic class you can ask for concrete classes.

TLDR: The fact that two classes have the Interface, don't mean you **must** use them from there abstraction.